# Warming up RAM for columnstore after restart

Tags: singlestore

Imagine that my MemSQL database consisted of column-store tables only. Do I need to warm-up RAM with any data that is stored on-disk in column-store format or I can execute queries right after MemSQL is up and ready?

Answer (score 2):

You can execute queries immediately after restarting. Depending on the workload and hardware, it is possible there would be a performance benefit to warming up and therefore caching data in memory, but it is certainly not necessary.

Comment: Thanks! That's a kind of explanation I tried to find in MemSQL documentation.